# How to Year range start year end year in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to fix Year range start year in datepicker Datetime in ASP.NET MVC?

My code is

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-60:+0"
        });

    });
</script>
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Model.GenderList, "- Select Gender -", new { @class = "form-control" })


@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Dateofbirth, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" }).
```

Here my question is how to fix year range in `dateofbirth` field datepicker depends on gender value..

Ex:

```
Gender==Male dateofbirth year select Option starts from (currentYear - 21)
Gender==Female dateofbirth year select Option starts from (currentYear - 18)
```

After selecting gender value change change year range in dateofbirth field else show error message.

Comment: make a gerneric method - put your logics inside, after changing in gender call this method.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

`jQuery` `Datepicker` has a `yearRange property` which `allows user` to set the `start` and `end year` range that will be `displayed` the `Year Dropdown` within the `jQuery  Datepicker`.

> The syntax of the value is `'{Start-Year}:{End-Year}'`

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
});
 $('.date-picker2').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
});
  });
   </script>
```

**run code in js fiddle:**

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/karthicbe/DBpJe/15325/)